# How do I change the shared components, tools, and SDKs path in VisualStudio Community2022 since there is no VisualStudio directory in my registry

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am new to learning the C++ renderer engine and I need to install some workloads and components in Visual Studio 2022, I would like to install them in my E drive but it seems that VS2022 doesn't allow me to change the location where they are installed (I have installed them once before).

I found that there is no Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft directory in my registry editor.

I don't know how to fix this.BTW my OS is Windows 11 Home Edition